# Select item from simple list with jmespath query

Tags: ansible

I have a simple list with strings. I want to select the item in the list based  on the presence of a predefined string 'fixedaddress'. I created a query and I expect the query to return the first item/string from the example input list, but it is retruning the following error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "JMESPathError in json_query filter plugin:\nIn function contains(), invalid type for value: fixedaddress/ZG5zLmZpeGVkX2FkZHJlc3MkMTAuMjM5LjEyLja, expected one of: ['array', 'string'], received: \"unknown\""}
```

Input (strings are shortened because of sensitive info, rest of the string contains another : and /, not sure if that is related to the error):

```
{
    [
        "fixedaddress/ZG5zLmZpeGVkX2FkZHJlc3MkMTAuMjM5LjEyLja",
        "record:a/ZG5zLmJpbmRfYSQuMjMubmwubW9kLG1hcmMwMDAxLW1"
    ]
}
```

Ansible code:

```
- name: "Delete IP Record: Task 2.2a: Filter Results."
  vars:
    jmesquery: "[?contains(@,`fixedaddress`)]"
  set_fact:
    ip_record_ref: "{{ ip_record_refs | json_query(jmesquery) }}"
  when: ip_record_refs | length > 1
```

Comment: ["It's not working" is not an accurate description of your problem](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). Meanwhile => `{{ ip_record_ref | select('match', 'fixedaddress') }}`

Comment: And even using your above example code if you really want to use `json_query`, [I can't reproduce your issue](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/12bf3ace6aa2bf7867fbcb41954c3d43) (based on what I guess is the result you expect)

Comment: You solution works. I also would like to understand how to do this with a JMESpath based query since I am trying to get some experience with that as well.

Comment: Your solution works as well :) See my reproduce link.

Comment: Please do not add necessary information to answer you question in comments, especially with large portions of code/output. [edit] your question. Moreover, before you proceed, read [ask] and pay attention to the [mre] section. You can also take my reproduce link as an example if you wish. Also make sure you have an up-to-date ansible/jinja2 stack. Thanks.

Comment: After your latest edit, to make my last comment even clearer, what is needed is a **minimal but complete** playbook that anyone can copy and paste in it's own environment and the exact command you used to run it with its complete output to reproduce the problem (or not...). Once again before all that, make sure you have the latest versions for ansible, jinja2 and jmespath in your python environment (i.e. `pip install --upgrade ansible jinja2 jmespath`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Apparently the Ansible version we are using has a bug. See also:

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/27299

So workaround was to use the following as JMESpath query:

ip_record_ref: "{{ ip_record_refs | to_json | from_json | json_query(jmesquery) }}"

Comment: Please do not use outdated ansible versions The currently maintained minimal ansible-core version is 2.12 with an EOL in a few days. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html#return-values. So please upgrade to 2.13 at least. This is basically as easy as `pip install --upgrade ansible`. Moreover, please give the ansible version your are running in your question, especially when people have been able to show you they cannot reproduce your problem. Thanks